# How can I create a .dmg file to allow deployment of a .NetCore 3.1 app on MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

I have a.NetCore 3.1 Forms application in C# created with VS 2019 v 16.8.2 on Windows 10. How can I create a dmg file to allow deployment on MacOS (Catalina).

Comment: If by "forms" you mean "WinForms", my understanding was that WinForms was still Windows-only. Has that changed/am I mistaken?

Comment: WinForms apps using .Net Framework is Windows only, but VS 2019 16.82.2 can now create .Net Core apps with forms and a designer, which presumably will run on MacOS.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you can create WinForms applications using .NET Core. Re-read my comment.

Comment: Even the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms) for its code states: _"Windows Forms (WinForms) is a UI framework for building **Windows desktop applications. It is a .NET wrapper over Windows user interface libraries, such as User32 and GDI+.** It also offers controls and other functionality that is unique to Windows Forms."_

Answer (score 2):

According to MS announcement WinForms, WPF will run only on Windows - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/.
The whole point was to move WPF and WinForms to target .Net Core, which doesn't automatically makes them cross-platform.